# Typescript error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null at HTMLButtonElement.document.getElementById.addEventListener.event

Tags: typescript

Hello I am having trouble with this simple calculator in Typescript and I can't seem to find the issue. I don't know why I am getting the value null because it seems to me the Id's on the elements are correct

HTML :

```
X: <input type="text" id="x" > &nbsp;
Y: <input type="text" id="y" >
<br>

<button  id="Add">Add</button> &nbsp;&nbsp;
<button  id="Subtract">Subtract</button>

<span id="output"></span>
```

TS:

`window.onload = function() {
    var calc = new Calculator('X','Y','Output');
}


class Calculator {
    private x: HTMLInputElement;
    private y: HTMLInputElement;
    private output: HTMLSpanElement;

    constructor(xId: string, yId:string,outputId:string) {
        this.x = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById(xId);
        this.y = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById(yId);
        this.output = <HTMLSpanElement>document.getElementById(outputId);
        this.wireEvents();
    }

    wireEvents() {
        document.getElementById('Add').addEventListener('click',event => {
            this.output.innerHTML = this.add(parseInt(this.x.value), parseInt(this.y.value)).toString()
        });
        document.getElementById('Subtract').addEventListener('click',event => {
            this.output.innerHTML = this.subtract(parseInt(this.x.value), parseInt(this.y.value)).toString();
        });
    };

    add(x:number,y:number) {
        return x+y;
    }
    subtract(x:number,y:number){
        return x-y; 
    }

}`

Answer (score 0):

## It's a typo: Lowercase vs Uppercase

In your `HTML` your `id`s are in **lowercase**

```
X: <input type="text" id="x" > &nbsp;
Y: <input type="text" id="y" >
```

Then in your `TypeScript` you write them in **uppercase**

```
var calc = new Calculator('X','Y','Output');
```

The `id` attribute [being case-sensitive](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#casesens) will make the `document.getElementById` return `undefined`

```
// this.x is undefined here
this.x = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById(xId);
```

## Solution

Replace `X` with `x` and `Y` with `y`

```
 var calc = new Calculator('x','y','Output');
```